# Would it be reasonable to ask this in SXSE?

Tags: discussion

I asked the question [Who must approve a globally distributed satellite to ground laser communication system?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32332/14213) a while ago in aviation statckexchange, and it met some resistance, but ultimately no answer despite a bounty.

I'm wondering if I should ask a similar question in SXSE. It's past the deadline to migrate.

It would of course be much shorter. The question grew as I repeatedly had to add material to counter false claims in comments trying to close. I think it was just too non-standard for that SE at that time.

Here I'd just ask something like "Who must approve a world-wide network of ground-space-ground internet laser beams? How might they avoid skies full of airplanes?

Would this be a reasonable question to ask and not be considered cross-posting?

I might include additional examples of companies interested in optical communications, perhaps some that have been in the news more recently.

Comment: After thinking about the comment Michael Kjorling left under my answer, could you flag that question on Aviation as 'in need of moderator attention' and request migration to space.stackexchange? I looked in Meta.stackexchange for info on whether a moderator can indeed migrate an old question even if the time limit has expired, and did not find an answer. And now i think i should get back to work, so i'm tossing the ball to you.

Comment: @kimholder No please I really don't want it migrated. That question bears several war-wounds from battling attempted closes. It can be asked here without needing to be so defensive, because it's more familliar subject matter. And there can really be both aviation and space perspectives to the answer. Thank you for asking and for the reminder, I'll ask very soon. But you or anyone else are *more than welcome* to post the question fresh here instead! That would be great and a welcomed help.

Comment: Sadly, i have had to curtail my activity on space.se to a very high degree because i am working on Moonwards. I can't take time right now to ask questions unless they immediately bear on my work, and most of the time, what i do is so open-ended it is hard to ask about it within the framework SE uses. But uhoh, don't feel you need to personally by yourself keep the question count up. Do what you enjoy here. Space.SE is coming along, i can say from personal experience it is better not to worry about it.

Comment: @kimholder I have hiking, biking, coffee, reading and stackexchange, and I try not to do SE while I am hiking or biking. I'm still waiting for Stackexchange, the Movie to be released. Have you heard a date yet? (note, there is this 2nd order effect of needing to eat and find shelter during typhoons as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is actually not possible to migrate the Aviation.SE question, it definitely isn't cross-posting, and since it concerns satellites, it  definitely has to do with space. That's all that really needs to be known. Go ahead and ask.

Comment: I agree with Kim.

Comment: Any question can be migrated from anywhere to anywhere within the Stack Exchange network. OP just needs to flag it for moderator attention where it is and request migration to wherever they want it to go. A diamond moderator can migrate to any site, not just those that have community migration paths established. I'm not sure how it works with questions that are "too old to migrate", as this one is, but I suspect it's still possible with a diamond.

Comment: Excellent point @MichaelKjörling. A brief look around meta.SE didn't locate an answer as to whether a mod can do this, so i've invited uhoh to flag the Aviation question just to see.